# How to verify the Json response field data type in rest assured test

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, testng, assert, rest-assured

How can we verify the Json data type of mentioned fields such as "price", "ck", "name", "enabled" and "tags" in rest assured test.

```
{
  "odd": {
    "price": 200,
    "ck": 12.2,
    "name": "test this",
    "enabled": true,
    "tags": null
  }
}
```

Is there any way or any assertion library which provide data type verification as mentioned in rest assured test example where instead of asserting the actual value of given key we can verify only the data type

```
ValidatableResponse response =
            
given().
    spec(requestSpec).
    headers("authkey", "abcdxxxxxxxxxyz").
    pathParam("uid", oddUid).
when().
    get("/orders" + "/{uid}").
then().
    assertThat().
    statusCode(200).
    body(
           "odd.price",  isNumber(),
           "odd.name", isString(),
           "enabled", isboolean()
           "tags", isNull()
         );
```

Comment: You seem to have provided the answer already. Are you going through an error? Can you detail it?

Comment: Hello https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/12740/jo%c3%a3o-farias
I am not sure about the which library to use for this kind of assrtions

Comment: You are already making the assertions. You mean that your second block of code is not working or it is just pseudo-code?

Comment: Yes..it is pseudo-code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72955760/8343843